# Como encerrar Node.js na aplicação?

Tags: node.js

Como faço para parar uma aplicação Node.JS?

---

Por exemplo, no PHP, temos algo assim:

```
exit;
```

Ou:

```
die('Mensagem.');
```

Há algum meio de parar a aplicação Node.js desse jeito (ou parecido), sem ter que usar o <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>?

Comment: `process.exit()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há duas maneiras por meio do objeto `process`:

[(1)](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/process.html#process_process_abort) `process.abort()`

[(2)](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) `process.exit(codigoDeSaida)`

O primeiro aborta o programa na hora, normalmente para coisas anormais.

O segundo manda o Node sair do programa "graciosamente" com um código de saída opcional (que pode significar um erro).